# sed replace "),(" with a newline "\n"

Tags: regex, sed

I have a sql file and I want to separate every statement in a new line. To do this I need to replace "),(" with "\n". I tried the following but I doesn't work:

```
sed ’s/\),\(/\n/’ tables.sql
```

Thanks

Comment: Take care, you're not using plain single quotes up there.

Comment: Also, it would be great to explain "it doesn't work" in greater detail. Do you get results that you do not expect?  What are they?  Is there an error?  If so, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escaped parenthesis in sed are capture groups. The syntax would be:

```
$ echo $'(a),(b)' | sed 's/),(/\\n/g'
(a\nb)
```

Comment: Right. The alternative would be noisier: `sed -r 's/\),\(/\n/'`

Comment: Or `sed -E` in OSX or various other BSDs.